# Generate in oracle sql developer a point with specific SRID from two variables

Tags: geoserver, oracle-spatial

I have created quite often (in posgis) points using two variables from the table (LAT,LON) and setting the desired SRID.
I am trying to do something similar now with Oracle SQL developer but I keep getting errors when I try to display this as a layer in geoserver.
This is what I try:

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  CO_NAME,
  ADJUSTMENT_FACTOR, 
  MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(null,2100,SDO_POINT_TYPE(24.004632439599,24.004632439599,NULL),NULL,NULL) AS GEOM
 FROM CENTRAL_OFFICES
```

Instead of the variables LAT and LNG I have just put two random numbers. Moreover I want to ask how is possible to view in a readable format the generated geometry. Something like: ST_ASTEXT of postgis.

**EDIT**

I have written this query:

```
SELECT ID,
  CO_NAME,
  ADJUSTMENT_FACTOR,
  PORT_LOCATION,
  VDSL_ENABLED, 
  SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(
    SDO_GEOMETRY(2100,4326,
      SDO_POINT_TYPE(CAST(REPLACE(CENTRAL_OFFICES.LAT, '.', ',') AS FLOAT), CAST(REPLACE(CENTRAL_OFFICES.LNG, '.', ',') 
        AS FLOAT),NULL),NULL,NULL),2100))    AS  geom
  FROM CENTRAL_OFFICES
```

This returns a table with a point geometry in the desired SRID (2100).

Comment: You're not specifying an SRID in object creation.  Please **edit** the question to report the error message contents exactly.  Did you mean to specify X == Y for the coordinate?

Comment: As far I read in documentation the SRID is the second parameter; thus 2100. The first parameter is the type of geometry. In any case I have edited my question in order to show how the query creates the points transformed in the desired SRID (2100). Also the points are in readable format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written this query:

```
SELECT ID,
  CO_NAME,
  ADJUSTMENT_FACTOR,
  PORT_LOCATION,
  VDSL_ENABLED, 
  SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(
    SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,4326,
      SDO_POINT_TYPE(CAST(REPLACE(CENTRAL_OFFICES.LNG, '.', ',') AS FLOAT), CAST(REPLACE(CENTRAL_OFFICES.LAT, '.', ',') 
        AS FLOAT),NULL),NULL,NULL),2100))    AS  geom
  FROM CENTRAL_OFFICES
```

This returns a table with a point geometry in the desired SRID (2100).

Comment: If you feel your converted point geometry is not in the right spot, check `select mdsys.sdo_cs.determine_chain(null, null, 4326, 2100) from dual` and make sure code 1272 is mentioned somewhere in the transform chain.

Comment: The "2100" in this shape is the geometry type. 2100 is not a valid type. For a 2D point, the proper type is 2001 (2 stands for 2D and the final 01 means it is a point). 4326 is the SRID. Here it means that the coordinates are in WGS84 (GPS) coordinates. Finally the coordinates are always in (X,Y) sequence, i.e. (longitude,latitude) - not (latitude,longitude) as written.

Comment: @Albert Godfrind Seen and fixed

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the CENTRAL_OFFICES table looks like this (simplified).

```
create table central_offices (
  id number primary key,
  lat number,
  lng number
);
```

Let's fill it with sample data:

```
insert into central_offices (id, lat, lng) values (1, 39.018483, 22.9983436);
commit;
```

The select to achieve what you want is then like this (assuming that lat and long are decimal degrees in WGS84 aka GPS coordinates)

```
select id, 
  sdo_cs.transform (
    sdo_geometry (2001, 4326, sdo_point_type(lng, lat, null), null,null),
    2100
  ).get_wkt()
from central_offices;
```

Notice this uses the get_wkt() method to get the results in OGC WKT (function SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY does the same).

**IMPORTANT**: notice that coordinates are always stored in **(X,Y)** order, which for geodetic coordinates means **(longitude, latitude)** - not (latitude,longitude) as originally written.

In your example it looks like the coordinates are stored as strings with a point as decimal separator - something like "39.018483". You can use those strings directly in the SDO_GEOMETRY constructor: the conversion from string to number happens automatically.

**BUT**: that happens in the context of the **locale** you use in your session. Since 2100 is a Greek system, I assume you are in Greece, and so use a Greek locale where the decimal separator is a comma. If you try converting the above string to a number, you will get the following error:

```
SQL> select to_number('39.018483') from dual;
select to_number('39.018483') from dual
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: μη αποδεκτός αριθμός
```

You could replace '.' with ',' the way you do, but a better way is just to tell the database to use a point as decimal separator:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_numeric_characters = '.,';
Session altered.

SQL> select to_number('39.018483') from dual;

TO_NUMBER('39.018483')
----------------------
             39.018483

1 row selected.
```

Let's try that with the CENTRAL_OFFICES table that uses strings for the coordinates:

```
create table central_offices (
  id number primary key,
  lat varchar2(20),
  lng varchar2(20)
);

insert into central_offices (id, lat, lng) values (1, '39.018483', '22.9983436');
commit;
```

Without the separator setting, the query will fail:

```
select id, 
  sdo_cs.transform (
    sdo_geometry (2001, 4326, sdo_point_type(lng, lat, null), null,null),
    2100
  ).get_wkt()
from central_offices;
ERROR:
ORA-01722: μη αποδεκτός αριθμός
```

With the setting, it works fine:

```
alter session set nls_numeric_characters = '.,';

select id, 
  sdo_cs.transform (
    sdo_geometry (2001, 4326, sdo_point_type(lng, lat, null), null,null),
    2100
  ).get_wkt()
from central_offices;

  ID SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,4326,SDO_POINT_TYPE(LNG,LAT,NULL),NULL,NULL)
---- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1 POINT (413136.397473566 4319017.56676377)
```